# When I run the test is returned me the following error:Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: java, hibernate

[Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: sessionfactory.EmployeeDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POMXu.jpg)

```
package sessionfactory;

public class EmployeeDetails {

    private int empno;
    private String empName, Email;
    private double salary;

    public int getEmpno() {
        return empno;
    }

    public void setEmpno(int empno) {
        this.empno = empno;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your code, put your error not and image of error please

Comment: package sessionfactory;
public class EmployeeDetails {
 private int empno;
 private String empName,Email;
 private double salary;
 public int getEmpno() {
  return empno;
 }
 public void setEmpno(int empno) {
  this.empno = empno;
 }
 public String getEmpName() {
  return empName;
 }
 public void setEmpName(String empName) {
  this.empName = empName;
 }
 public String getEmail() {
  return Email;
 }
 public void setEmail(String email) {
  Email = email;
 }
 public double getSalary() {
  return salary;
 }public void setSalary(double salary) {
  this.salary = salary;}}

Comment: Like i said bellow your real package is `package sessionfactory;` not `com.hibernateexample` so try to put your entity in the right place or correct the other side

Comment: put your error here you can edit your question when you want, don't put it in the comment

Comment: You use an entity in a mapping of another entity but this last not exist in your package :

    com.hibernateexample.EmployeeDetails

So check if you call the right entity `EmployeeDetails` from the right package `com.hibernateexample`.